# Wordpress Subdomain add comment redirect to 404 not found page iis server

Tags: wordpress, comments, http-status-code-404, multisite

I am using a subdomain with Wordpress and am traying to add comment, after submitting I have redirected to 404 page not found because the wp-comments-post.php file is into root directory and in my exemple the URL show *mysite.com/**subdiectory**/wp-comments-post.php*

[image: 404 not found]

And this is my web.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule> 
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
         <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
            </files>
         </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Just for completeness I add a rule to the web.config file :

```
<rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-comments-post.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
</rule>
```